# php mysql Search for all $VAR

Tags: php, mysql, database

Can anybody see how i would code this correctly instead of the route i have chosen,

Basically i wish to filter all fields if selected

from options

collection
delivery
local collection
or All

I can query correctly up until i wish to pull all from the database

The code below will explain a little more.

I have had to make a seperate query to pull all because i couldnt find any other way.

But if anybody has a little advice of how i could do this id be most greatfull

THE DATABASE HAS (DELIVERY) YES / NO / YES LOCAL , But my query can only pull those choices, but i also want to be able to pull all of them too. But i dont know how i would write the query.

SEE CODE BELOW.

```
        if ($delivery==="collection") { $delivery="no";}
        if ($delivery==="delivery") {$delivery="yes";}
        if ($delivery==="local") {$delivery="yes local";}

        if ($delivery==="either") {$delivery="either";}

if ($delivery != "either")    
{       
$query="SELECT * FROM testdata WHERE title LIKE ? AND location LIKE ? AND postcode LIKE ? AND price >=? AND price <=? AND cond=? AND catagory LIKE ? AND delivery=? ORDER BY $order $dir";

$stat=$db->prepare($query);

$stat->execute(array("%$searchfor%","%$location%","%$postcode%","$pricefrom","$priceto","$cond","%$catagory%","$delivery"));
}           



if ($delivery==="either") { $query="SELECT * FROM testdata WHERE title LIKE ? AND location LIKE ? AND postcode LIKE ? AND price >=? AND price <=? AND cond=? AND catagory LIKE ? ORDER BY $order $dir"; 

$stat=$db->prepare($query);

$stat->execute(array("%$searchfor%","%$location%","%$postcode%","$pricefrom","$priceto","$cond","%$catagory%"));

}
```

I Hope you can make sense out of the code, Im not sure if iv explained myself very well..

Comment: If your database has fixed values then do not use LIKE in the query otherwise it will pull in all the similar data i.e. yes AND yes local. so your query needs to be adjusted to $query="SELECT * FROM testdata WHERE title LIKE ? AND location ?

Comment: they not all fixed, the LIKE's are genuine wildcards, But the $Delivery are set for a reason. so user can select either Delivery or not. But im not sure how i would pull all the rows in the same query if user selects Either. Eitherway i think it required a separate query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL WHERE IN condition:

```
$delivery_con = [];
if ($delivery==="collection") { $delivery_con="no";}
if ($delivery==="delivery") {$delivery_con="yes";}
if ($delivery==="local") {$delivery_con="yes local";}

if ($delivery==="either") {$delivery_con="no,yes,yes local";}


$query="SELECT * FROM testdata WHERE title LIKE ? AND location LIKE ? AND postcode LIKE ? AND price >=? AND price <=? AND cond=? AND catagory LIKE ? AND delivery IN (?) ORDER BY $order $dir";

$stat=$db->prepare($query);

$stat->execute(array("%$searchfor%","%$location%","%$postcode%","$pricefrom","$priceto","$cond","%$catagory%",$delivery_con));
```

Comment: iv managed to sort out the yes local by changing it to local, But now im back to square 1, im not getting any results for Either...But the query you offered is working other than that, im gonna have to try and figure it out for myself, But thank you for your input, im 3/4 way there.

Comment: i have edited the answer again. this will help you. use raw string instead of imploding array.

Answer (score 0):

Blooming typical, the answer was staring in my face all along

(if ($delivery==="either") {$delivery=null;})

(ANSWER / WITH A LIKE WILDCARD(Just carefull of how you label your database)

```
     if ($catagory==="View All") {$catagory=null;}

     if ($delivery==="either") {$delivery=null;}

     if ($cond==="both") {$cond=null;}


        if ($delivery==="collection") { $delivery="no";}
        if ($delivery==="delivery") {$delivery="yes";}
        if ($delivery==="local") {$delivery="local";}







$query="SELECT * FROM testdata WHERE title LIKE ? AND location LIKE ? AND postcode LIKE ? AND price >=? AND price <=? AND cond LIKE ? AND catagory LIKE ? AND delivery LIKE ? ORDER BY $order $dir";

$stat=$db->prepare($query);

$stat->execute(array("%$searchfor%","%$location%","%$postcode%","$pricefrom","$priceto","%$cond%","%$catagory%","%$delivery%"));
```